# Unique Filter with OR and AND conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a list of Unique Values with based on different criteria.

```
1100 | IT5   | Evo 
1200 | IT5   | Bug 
1300 | IT5   | Evo 
1300 | IT5   | Evo
1400 | IT5.2 | Iss
1400 | IT5.2 | Iss
1400 | IT5.2 | Iss
1500 | IT1   | Bug
```

Expected list is

```
1200
1400
```

I'm currently using follwing filter : `=UNIQUE(FILTER($A$3:$A$1000;($B$3:$B$1000="IT5")*($C$3:$C$1000<>"Evo")))`

However, record 1400 is missing because the filter is apply on IT5 only ...

Is it possible to do a filter with a OR condition to get IT5.2 ? Like the AND with *.

(Note that it is an example, I need to apply a filter on 5 columns)

Many thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: please do not edit the question to include new criteria after you get an answer.  It invalidates the answer and opens them up for down votes.  Please ask a new question instead.

Comment: Oh ok I will do it so.

Comment: Please find below the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143946/unique-filter-with-several-or-and-and-conditions

Comment: To add a criteria use `*` for `AND` and/or `+` for `OR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ISNUMBER(SEARCH())

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER($A$3:$A$1000;(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("IT5";$B$3:$B$1000)))*($C$3:$C$1000<>"Evo")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However I missed an information on my question so I updated it. I still need to use ISNUMBER(SEARCH()) to combine the different criterias ?

Comment: Updating an answer with new criteria is inappropriate after getting an answer.

Comment: Of course, please find below the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143946/unique-filter-with-several-or-and-and-conditions